# Cannot ping a tap device with ipv6 address

Tags: centos, networking, ipv6, tap

I'm running CentOS 7.

First I created a tap device:

```
ip tuntap add dev tap2 mode tap
```

Then I assigned ipv6 address to it:

```
ip -6 addr add dev tap2 fd00:4::1/64
ip link set tap2 up
```

Its state generated from `ip addr` shows:

```
tap2: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DEFAULT qlen 500
link/ether fe:ea:2b:e0:c3:08 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

However, `ping6 fd00:4::1` receives nothing. `tcpdump -i tap2` also outputs nothing.

Is tap device ready for running in ipv6? Should I add configuration somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your version of `ip` supports it, you could use the confflag **`nodad`** to tell the device to skip **Duplicate Address Detection (DAD)** when assigning the address:

```
# ip -6 addr add dev tap2 fd00:4::1/64 nodad
```

Probably the DAD cannot be done since the tap device is not connected to any medium. When assigning the address *without* the confflag, an `ip addr` shows me (Ubuntu, kernel 3.13, iproute2 version 3.12.0) that the address is in *tentative* state, i.e. it is waiting for DAD to finish:

```
3: tap2: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 500
    link/ether 6a:fe:48:a1:b2:1d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fd00:4::1/64 scope global tentative
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Assigning *with* the confflag `nodad` shows a different result:

```
3: tap2: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 500
    link/ether 6a:fe:48:a1:b2:1d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fd00:4::1/64 scope global nodad 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Ping works then:

```
# ping6 fd00:4::1
PING fd00:4::1(fd00:4::1) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from fd00:4::1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.050 ms
64 bytes from fd00:4::1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.056 ms
...
```